# I can't see my Flash SWF online

Tags: flash

I imported my SWF unto Dreamweaver and previewed it on browser and it works perfectly fine, I then uploaded it on the server but it is not showing online, I have Flash player 10, and I have checked to see if all the files are placed in correct root folder. I tried to save the SWF under a new name, and a few other things but it is not working! I have been racking my brains for 2 weeks....

Here is the site page: www.solidminddojo.co.uk

Please, can anyone help?

Comment: url does not have any flash! where are we looking?

Answer (score 0):

There's no SWF or anything Flash related in your page. You forgot to add it to your HTML.

To add it, add this code to your page, where it should be.

```
<object width="WIDTH" height="HEIGHT">
<param name="movie" value="YourSWFName.swf">
<embed src="YourSWFName.swf" width="WIDTH" height="HEIGHT">
</embed>
</object>
```